# Split FileList into individual file input elements

Tags: javascript, dom, filelist

Is it possible to split a `FileList` instance (from a drop event, `event.dataTransfer.fileList`), and assing each file within it to an *individual* `<input type="file" ... />` element?

For example, to assign all files (1 or more...) from a drop event to an input element `fileInputElement`, you would:

```js
function dropHandler(event) {
  fileInputElement.files = event.dataTransfer.files;
}
```

I'm looking for something like:

```js
function dropHandler(event) {
  // assume fileEls is an array of input[type=file] elements
  for (var i = 0; i < event.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {

    // yep, FileList.push doesn't exist..
    fileEls[i].files.push(event.dataTransfer.files.item(i));

    // and this (imagined) FileList constructor is not available...
    fileEls[i].files = new FileList([event.dataTransfer.files.item(i)]);
  }
}
```

A signs point to **nope, can't do it**...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new `FileList` through [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer)

```
function dropHandler(event) {
  // assume fileEls is an array of input[type=file] elements
  for (var i = 0; i < event.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {

    // Create a new DataTransfer
    var dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

    // Add the items
    dataTransfer.items.add(event.dataTransfer.files.item(i));

    // Get the FileList
    fileEls[i].files = dataTransfer.files;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If fileEls is an array already, try

fileEls.push(event.dataTransfer.files.item(i));

you could also do:

fileEls[i].files = clone(event.dataTransfer.files.item);

There are numbers of clone (preferrably deepclone) function around the web.

Comment: `fileEls` is an array of `input` elements. `event.dataTransfer.files.item(i)` yields a `File` type. `fileEls[i].files` is a `FileList`, so it doesn't make sense to replace that with a `File` (from `event.dataTransfer.files.item(i)`)